# How to process all but a particular element of a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of ids and am trying to do some processing, using eq function on a dataframe object, on all but a particular element of the list. Can you please suggest me how it can be done?

```
ids = list(set(df['user_id']))
for k in ids:
    #processing = df.user_id.eq(ids-{k}????)
```

Comment: Can you try to solve the problem and come back with an attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to watch out for this is that you don't want to be destructively modifying the ids list as you are looping through it to remove the current element. Thus, one way we can do this is to loop through the indexes and, for each index i, create a new spliced together list that contains all the elements in ids other than at index i. I would do it as such:

```
for i in range(len(ids)):
    elemsExcludingi = ids[:i] + ids[i + 1:]
    # use this list to do things
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can set an if statement in the for-loop, where `target_id is` the id you do not which to process

```
ids = list(set(df['user_id']))
for k in ids:
    if k != target_id:
        #processing code goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use the keyword `continue`.

While in a loop whenever the keyword `continue` is called, it makes the loop to iterate over it leaving the code below unprocessed.

```
ids = list(set(df['user_id']))
for k in ids:
    if k == 'the_element_you_dont_want':
        continue #Skips the code below when its called 
    #Other code code block
    #processing = df.user_id.eq(ids-{k}????)
```